# iOS NSJSON Returning Null

Tags: iphone, ios, nsjsonserialization

I have the following code

```
 hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];    

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization 
                        JSONObjectWithData:dataURL
                        options:kNilOptions 
                        error:&error];

NSArray *files = [result objectForKey:@"GV_Return"];

NSLog(@"Files: %@", files);

// For Each Key we seperate the data and add it to an object to be used.
for (NSDictionary *file in files)
{           
NSString *userNumber = [result objectForKey:@"UserNumber"];
NSLog(@"output: %@", userNumber);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that **NSLog(@"Files: %@", files);** returns what I expect

```
Files: (
    {
    UserNumber = 1;
}
)
```

However **NSLog(@"output: %@", userNumber);** Returns **NULL**

I need help figuring out why  NSString *userNumber = [result objectForKey:@"UserNumber"]; does not seem to be returning "1" as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
for (NSDictionary *file in files)
{           
NSString *userNumber = [file objectForKey:@"UserNumber"];
NSLog(@"output: %@", userNumber);
}
```

i.e. `file objectForKey...`, not `result objectForKey...`. You're iterating through the `files` array with each entry in it being identified as `file` for the purposes of the code within the for loop.

Comment: Yup figured it out and was posting the solution when you answered. I had just copied/pasted NSArray *files = [result objectForKey:@"GV_Return"]; and forgot to change result to file. That's what I get for taking a shortcut. Thanks.