# responseString is null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

my webservice returns json string with new lines so It causes  problem that responseString gives always null.

```
NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:kampanyadata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"responsestring:%@",responseString]);
```

> ----responsestring:null

how can I replaces new lines character in JSON String?

Comment: Have you ever considered SBJSON? Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *tempString = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

I think you need to do this :)

Comment: No ı cant do it becuse I get null values .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578719/json-parser-returns-null and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424040/ios-nsjson-returning-null do have look at these posts, hope it helps out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure kampanyadata is not null? If it's not null try to use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` like this:

```
NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:kampanyadata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];.
```

Offtopic

And btw the `NSLog();` method takes a NSString formatted already as parameter so you can use:

```
NSLog(@"responsestring:%@",responseString);
```

Comment: Thanks It works.But I have to encode responsestring with NSUTF8StringEncoding .How can ı do it?

Comment: Well the data is not encoded from the begining with UTF8, so that is why it's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    soapResults = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]
                    length:[webData length]
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

try this this works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You got some NSData, and you tried to convert it to an NSString. There's no JSON involved at this point. Any errors have nothing to do with JSON or newline characters whatsoever. Possibilities: 1. The NSData that you received is nil. 2. The NSData that you received isn't in UTF-8 format.

Your NSLog statement is quite funny. Look at the definition of NSLog - the first parameter is a format string. Instead of

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"responsestring:%@",responseString]);
```

you should write

```
NSLog (@"responseString:%@", responseString);
```

And you can pass the JSON document *directly* to NSJSONSerializer. No need to convert it to an NSString. Actually, if the data is large, just a waste of valuable memory.